# Unable to run pip install openai

Tags: python, pip

I believe that I have not installed PIP properly.
When I do `python3 -m pip --version  I get - pip 22.3.1 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)`

But then I do `pip install openai` I get - `zsh: command not found: pip`

I also tried doing - `brew install brew-pip`
And then tried doing - `export PYTHONPATH=$(brew --prefix)/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

What should I do? I am new on mac and have no idea how things work on mac.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your problem is directly calling pip there.

`pip install openai` will only work, if you are using an activated virtual environment, for example created via `python -m venv venv_name`.
The problem is, that pip is not an executable, normally available in your PATH variable.

The solution for you is to either create an environment as mentioned above and then activate it via `source venv_name/bin/activate` (this is the recommended solution, as you should not install packages to the global python).

Or to call `python -m pip install openai`. This solution is not recommended, as you normally should work with virtual environments only, because doing otherwise you could easily get conflicts with differing version numbers and such.

If you want any further information on using virtual environments, I recommend having a look at this page of the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)